# How do I parse a large XML file using Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am trying to parse an XML file using Java.

The XML file size is 256 kb only. I am using a DOM parser to parse the XML file. How can I parse the large XML file content?

Here's the method that parses the file content:

```
public Document parse_a_string(StringBuffer decodedFile) {
    Document doc1 = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();

         // problem here
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(decodedFile.toString()));

        doc1 = db.parse(inStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return doc1;
}
```

The file content is in the `StringBuffer` reference object, `decodedFile`, but when I set it to `StringReader` it accept only string.

Comment: StringBuffer has a toString() method to convert it to String. Check in JavaDoc before posting these questions

Comment: yes, but DecodedFile size is larger than string size. so we need to use stringbuffer. but in StringReader accept only string objects. my problem is how can we do parse large content which is present in stringbuffer.

Comment: Are you getting any errors while parsing it, like OutOfMemory? It might be something as simple as changing the Java memory settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read large XML file consisting of large number of small items efficiently in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653448/how-to-read-large-xml-file-consisting-of-large-number-of-small-items-efficiently)

Comment: No, am not getting any exception.

Comment: Also similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746950/parsing-very-large-xml-files-and-marshalling-to-java-objects, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301926/xml-process-large-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906892/parse-an-xml-string-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355909/parsing-very-large-xml-documents-and-a-bit-more-in-java, etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 5):

For large documents (though I wouldn't call your's large) I'd use [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) XML parsing library. It's miles ahead of the native Java parsers, and in my opinion, quite superior.

For the code you provided, you actually have to walk the DOM tree and retrieve elements. See [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/books/xmljava/) or the [official Java tutorial on working with XML](http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html) for more information on working with XML documents.

Comment: If the question is just on parsing the 256K file, JDom is good, as well as Dom4J or Xom.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at a [StAX implementation](http://sjsxp.java.net/) like [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/). It lets you pull elements from the parser, instead of the parser pushing data into the app, and lets you pause parsing.

Answer (score 2):

256Kb is a pretty small file nowadays: yesterday I was working with a 45Gb file which is a factor of 200,000 larger!

It's not clear what your problem is. Any of the normal Java parsing techniques will work perfectly well. Which of them you use depends on why you are parsing the file and what you want to do with the data.

Having said that, many people seem to choose DOM by default because it is so well entrenched. However, more modern object models such as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) or [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) are much easier to work with.

Comment: could you please tell what did you use to parse that 45Gb File, actually i need to parse a large XML file of the order of 40 - 50 gb to a TSV or CSV, could you please tell how should i approach this.?

Comment: I was using the streaming facilities in Saxon-EE, documented at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming.xml

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the file into a String/StringReader and all that jazz. Parse the file directly via `db.parse(new FileInputStream(...)).` Reading the file into memory just wastes memory, and time.